# How to bind the channel of rotation of the object to the position channel of another object?

Tags: animation

It is imperative for me to use the rotation channel along the x axis to smoothly change the position of the Empty object along the z axis. I tried to do this by using Object Constraint Transformation, but failed in its settings. The empty does not act as wanted.

Can someone help me with an example?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "Empty does not act as required?" Do you mean that parenting the object to the empty, and animating the empty is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can rather easily be achieved by using simple drivers. 
[I'd recommend watching this video series.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbjn7kaP877u1sX4zl081V8jUeSHDY18G) The first video explains pretty good how it works.

[Here is a quick recording i did,](https://youtu.be/fhvs8_Ar2gQ) showing how to do what you're asking.

Steps:

1. Select Empty, on transforms add a driver on Z Location.
2. In the input variables select the cube as input.
3. Change the type to X Rotation. Your Empty should now move along it's Z-axis when the cube is rotating around its X-axis
4. If you want to inverse the input, you can simply change the Expression from "var + 1" to "var * -1". (Multiplying something by negative 1 simply inverts its value)

Edit: And if you want to do it with a constraint, this setup seems to work for me:

[Gifycat showing it.](https://gfycat.com/dizzyimmensearkshell)

[image]

Don't know too much about how the Transformation constraint works, so can't really explain well why this work but it works. If you want to invert the axis just swap around the 90 and -90 on X rotation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering!

I made a short video to show that I need to ensure that when turning the object Zag_1_Rotation_Frame, the Empty object moves down a bit. This is to simulate a fake tube stretching down.
 
https://youtu.be/MyOQWRJIe0Y

To this Empty object using the Hook modifier, I attached the midpoints of the spline tubes.

Comment: After a little thought, I realized that it was necessary to make a connection not with Zag_1_Rotation_Frame x axis rotation, but with the object Empty.002 position (maybe with z axis loc), because it exactly most accurately displayed the movement of the tail of hydraulic cylinder. 
I have already tried the Transform modifier and the control through the drivers, but still nothing works for me. I definitely don’t understand something, or am doing something wrong, since I have only been working in Blender for a couple of months. And, obviously, for the time being I just don’t realize much.

Comment: I uploaded a sample of the scene, removing everything unnecessary on the Google disk. Maybe someone will help me and try to animate this thing as I intended? I will be grateful.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qN0IG4UyuAGQaMS2k94Y7vCrMwwHvQKm

Comment: @ИгорьКачанов [Quick video here.](https://youtu.be/rD8HgSqLTjM) Changing the Min/Max of the Z Loc will change how much up and down your empty travels. Settig it to a lov number means it only goes a bit up and down, setting it to a higher means the empty can go further up/down.
[Here's the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L941XsKgq4iv6ltXYclYzJKS30wTfyXZ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

After long attempts and alterations, I managed to make settings that, let's say ... satisfied me.

Made a **[small video](https://youtu.be/1g8s-aJf4Wg)** for demonstration.